# Wait until all the files are copied?

Tags: c, windows, file, winapi, copy

I am trying to find a way to wait until xcopy cmd finished copying files from a disk. I tried 2 ways. First way is basically waiting for `hprocess` from the created process.

But this `waitForSingleObject` never resolves.

```
void copyFileWait(){

  STARTinfP777.cb = sizeof(STARTinfP777);
  char allCmd[MAX_PATH] = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /k copy /y \""; // = drive letter; xcopy working fine
  printf("%s\n", allCmd);

  DWORD safsdkasf = 0;
  if(CreateProcess(NULL, allCmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &STARTinfP777, &procInf7777) == 0){

    printf("%d\n", GetLastError());
    MessageBox(0, "Hata", "Dikkat!", MB_OK);
    exit(0);
  }
  WaitForSingleObject( procInf7777.hProcess, INFINITE );
  CloseHandle( procInf7777.hProcess );
  CloseHandle( procInf7777.hThread );

}
```

In this function, i check the exitcode of the process after ran with `GetExitCodeProcess()` and also set a timer on the code. But it always equals to `259` i dont notice any change after even the files are completely written.

```
 void copyFileWait();
void gggPaths();
DWORD WINAPI GetDirsSEVENthreadFunc ();

//void cpyToPES(char fromWhereToCopy[MAX_PATH]);

char *WndCmpath = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe ";

HANDLE fileCopierHandle;
int Nprocess = 0;

STARTUPINFO STARTinfP777 = {0};
PROCESS_INFORMATION procInf7777 = {0};
DWORD exitcode;

int main(){

    gggPaths();

    //copyFileWait();

    DWORD threadCPYFilesID;
    fileCopierHandle=CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetDirsSEVENthreadFunc,(LPVOID)10,0,&threadCPYFilesID); //updating 0 olana kadar bekler
    WaitForSingleObject(fileCopierHandle,INFINITE);

    printf("done.");
    return 0;
}

void copyFileWait(){

  STARTinfP777.cb = sizeof(STARTinfP777);
    char allCmd[MAX_PATH] = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /k copy /y \""; // = drive letter; //xcopy files  bla bla works fine
    printf("%s\n", allCmd);



  DWORD safsdkasf = 0;
  if(exitcode != 259){
      if(CreateProcess(NULL, allCmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &STARTinfP777, &procInf7777) == 0){

        printf("%d\n", GetLastError());
        MessageBox(0, "Hata", "Dikkat!", MB_OK);
        exit(0);
      }
  }

  BOOL result = GetExitCodeProcess(procInf7777.hProcess, &exitcode);
  if(!result){
      memset( &STARTinfP777, '\0', sizeof STARTinfP777 );
      memset( &procInf7777, '\0', sizeof procInf7777 );
      printf("damn..\n");
      printf("%d\n", GetLastError());
  }else{

  }
  printf("exitcode => %d", exitcode);
  //if() exıtcode TASK_COMPLETE forexample... kill timer etc.
}


DWORD WINAPI GetDirsSEVENthreadFunc (){
  HWND tempHW;
  SetTimer(tempHW, 0, 5500,(TIMERPROC) &copyFileWait);
  MSG msg;
  while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){
   TranslateMessage(&msg);
   DispatchMessage(&msg);
 }
}
```

What would be a way to accomplish this task ?

I tried `CopyFile()` But it didnt find the path when i linked other volume letters, or external devices. Which I am working on.

Comment: `cmd.exe /k` doesn't exit until you type **exit** or close the window. That's the process you're running, not xcopy. Why not use `CopyFile` or `IFileOperation` instead?

Comment: @JonathanPotter is it about the '/k' argument or something ? As I said, I had issues with working on external volumes with `CopyFile`, For `IFileOperation` I haven't tried yet, `CopyFile` allows you to copy from external devices? I am sure I had the path and everything right.. )

Comment: Yes, specifically `/k`. It tells `cmd`, the process you are waiting for to exit, to not exit (automatically).

Comment: @JonathanPotter is it about the '/k' argument or something ? As I said, I had issues with working on external volumes with `CopyFile`, For `IFileOperation` I haven't tried yet, `CopyFile` allows you to copy from external devices? I am sure I had the path and everything right.. )

Comment: @ikegami what I could use instead

Comment: Just remove the `/k`

Comment: @ikegami i changed the file with the timer, after removing the `/k` command didnt run.

Comment: me bad. You gotta use `/c` instead. `/k` = run command and stay open, `/c` = run command and close

Comment: yeah i just did it lol @ikegami so all day tries for thiss ... Ty = ) All it takes is this site lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching `/k` to `/c` solved the problem.

Comment: If this does solve your issue, please feel free to mark yourself  to help people with the same question.